# Alternatives to commiting a transaction after onPause

Tags: android

I have a button. Upon clicking this button the current fragment should be replaced. It's working fine until I press the back button and then resume the activity. An exception saying `Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState.` occurs. I know that commit could cause state loss and I don't want state loss in my case. How do I make sure the replacement will be recovered upon resuming the activity?

Here's how I replace the current fragment:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.someId, SomeFragment.newInstance())
.commit();
```

Comment: Ah, can you please link the code where you replace the fragment?
It's no big mistake, but I suppose you forgot to addToBackstack.

Comment: @Vlad That's interesting. I don't have addToBackStack. I added the fragment replacing code to the question.

Comment: More interesting would be *where* you replace the fragment. Whereabouts in your Activity's lifecycle are you calling replace?

Comment: @tmalseed I'm thinking somewhere after onResume because I pressed the back button and then resumed the activity.

Comment: I'm asking where you execute the code above, is it only executed in the onClick of your button? It would help if you posted some more code.

Comment: @tmalseed Upon selection from a NavigationDrawer. I'll try to post more code if necessary.

Comment: My guess is that your NavigationDrawer 'selection' is being called without you necessarily pressing on the NavigationDrawer item, (when your Activity resumes, maybe it's 'selecting' the item for you?).

Comment: @tmalseed Yes the selection is being called, but in that case I still want to be able to replace the fragment using the selection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63826/discussion-between-tmalseed-and-b16db0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.someId, SomeFragment.newInstance())
.addToBackstack()
.commit();
```

This will fix ur problem I suppose.Post the code,so I can be sure.

//The answer completed.

You can use SharedPreferences to save the variables needed instead of using them as statics.This might be a "more viable" solution than having them as static vars.

Comment: As b16db0 said, you should show us where you replace the fragment.In which method.Just to be sure.But without the backstack, you won't achieve what you want.So this was the main problem.

Comment: Actually, I realized that this is not what I want. As I mentioned in the question, I want to be able to recover the possibly lost fragment state after resuming the application. This is still a useful answer anyway.

Comment: Glad I helped, maybe I can help a bit more though.

So ,what you need ,is to get state of the fragment , not the fragment itself,right?

I am not sure what exactly you are doing, but a workaround might be using the SharedPreferences.You can perhaps store your variables in there and than re-use them to build your fragment again- your UI.

If you are willing to show more code, I might be able to help a bit more.

Comment: Yup. I'm currently solving it by using static variables instead. I think SharedPreferences is another viable solution. If you want, you can make that your answer so I can "check" it.

Comment: For the record: changed the answer to the one I gave it in the comment. :)